# Matlab: How to survey compiled m-code progression from external API?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

My question is extremely specific to the arcanes of the matlab compiler and runtime. As only people familiar with matlab runtime API may answer, I shortened much details. Please let me know if I should be more verbose.

## Introduction

Using the matlab compiler & runtime I can call a function written in m-code from a C# program. Let's say calling:

```
function [result] = foo(n)
%[
    result = 0;
    for k = 1:n,
        pause(1.0); % simulate long processing
        result = result + 42;
    end
%]
```

with (somewhere behind some dllimports in the C# code):

```
mclFeval(IntPtr inst, string name, IntPtr[] plhs, IntPtr[] prhs)
```

So far, so good, I have no issue with this (i.e intializing the runtime, loading the '.cft' file, marshalling back and forth MxArray with .Net types, etc...)

## My Problem

I would like to survey the progression of my `foo` function using some `cancel` and `progress` callbacks:

```
function [result] = foo(n, cancelCB, progressCB)
%[
    if (nargin < 3), progressCB = @(ratio, msg) disp(sprintf('Ratio = %f, Msg = %s', ratio, msg)); end
    if (nargin < 2), cancelCB = @() disp('Checking cancel...'); end

    result = 0;
    for k = 1:n,

        if (~isempty(cancelCB)), 
            cancelCB(); % Up to the callback to raise some error('cancel');
        end;
        if (~isempty(progressCB)),  
           progressCB(k/n, sprintf('Processing (%i/%i)', k, n));
        end

        pause(1.0); % simulate long processing
        result = result + 42;
    end
%]
```

But of course I would like these callbacks to be in the C# code, not within the m-one.

## Investigations

1. Looking at 'mclmcr.h' header file, it looks like these functions may be of help:

   ```
   extern mxArray* mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(mxFunctionPtr fcn);
   extern bool mclRegisterExternalFunction(HMCRINSTANCE inst, const char* varname, mxFunctionPtr fcn);
   ```

   Unfortunatly these are fully undocumented and I found no use case I could mimic to understand how they work.
2. I've also thought about creating a COM visible object in C# and pass it as a parameter to the matlab code:

   ```
   // Somewhere within C# code:
   var survey = new ComSurvey();
   survey.SetCancelCallback =  () => { if (/**/) throw new OperationCancelException(); };
   survey.SetProgressCallback = (ratio, msg) => { /* do something */ };
   ```

   ```
   function [result] = foo(n, survey)
   %[
       if (nargin < 2), survey = []; end

       result = 0;
       for k = 1:n,

           if (~isempty(survey)),
              survey.CheckCancel(); % up to the COM object to raise exception
              survey.SetProgress(k/n, sprintf('Processing... %i/%i', k, n));
           end

           pause(1.0); % simulate long processing
           result = result + 42;
       end
   %]
   ```

   I'm very familiar with functions to create numeric and structure arrays and know how to use them:

   ```
   extern mxArray *mxCreateNumericArray(...)
   extern mxArray *mxCreateStructArray(...)
   ```

   Anyhow, how COM objects are packaged to MxArrays, I don't know?

## Further investigations

**Day+1**

Even if still unstable, I succeeded to have matlab to callback into my C# code and it seems that `mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle` is the direction to go.

**Note: Below code is for reference only. It may not be suitable in your own context as is. I'll provide simpler code later on (i.e. once I'll get stable solution).**

1. Looking to the signature of the `mxFunctionPtr`, I created two delegates like this:

   ```
   // Mimic low level signature for a Matlab function pointer
   [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
   delegate void MCRInteropDelegate(int nlhs, IntPtr[] plhs, int nrhs, IntPtr[] prhs);
   ```

   and

   ```
   // Same signature (but far more elegant from .NET perspective)
   delegate void MCRDelegate(MxArray[] varargouts, MxArray[] varargins);
   ```
2. I also linked to the runtime like this:

   ```
   [DllImport("mclmcrrt74.dll", EntryPoint = "mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
   static extern IntPtr _mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(MCRInteropDelegate fctn);
   ```
3. Assuming `MxArray` is a .NET class of mine that simply encapsulate for `mxArray*` handles, I then marshaled my delegates like this:

   ```
   // Create MxArray from corresponding .NET delegate
   static MxArray CreateFromDelegate(MCRDelegate del)
   {
       // Package high level delegate signature to a 'dllimport' signature
       MCRInteropDelegate interopDel = (nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs) =>
       {
           int k = 0;

           var varargouts = new MxArray[nlhs];
           var varargins = new MxArray[nrhs];

           // (nrhs, prhs) => MxArray[] varargins 
           Array.ForEach(varargins, x => new MxArray(prhs[k++], false)); // false = is to indicate that MxArray must not be disposed on .NET side

           // Call delegate
           del(varargouts, varargins); // Todo: varargouts created by the delegate must be destroyed by matlab, not by .NET !!

           // MxArray[] varargouts => (nlhs, plhs)
           k = 0;
           Array.ForEach(plhs, x => varargouts[k++].getPointer());
       };

       // Create the 1x1 array of 'function pointer' type
       return new MxArray(MCRInterop.mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(interopDel));
   }
   ```
4. Finally, assuming `module` is an instance of `MCRModule` (again, a class of mine to encapsulate `hInst*` in low level `mclFeval` API), I was able to call `foo` function and have it to enter my .NET `cancel` delegate like this:

   ```
   // Create cancel callback in .NET
   MCRDelegate cancel = (varargouts, varargins) =>
   {
       if ((varargouts != null) && (varargouts.Length != 0) { throw new ArgumentException("'cancel' callback called with too many output arguments"); } 
       if ((varargins != null) && (varargins.Length != 0) { throw new ArgumentException("'cancel' callback called with too many input arguments"); }

       if (...mustCancel...) { throw new OperationCanceledException(); }
   }

   // Enter the m-code
   // NB: Below function automatically converts its parameters to MxArray
   // and then call low level mclFeval with correct 'mxArray*' handles
   module.Evaluate("foo", (double)10, cancel);
   ```

   **This .NET code worked fine, and `foo` really made callback to the `cancel` delegate properly.**

   Only problem, is that it is quite unstable. My guess is that I used too many anonymous functions, and probably some of them are disposed too early ...

   **Will try to provide with stable solution within the next few days** (hopefully with simpler code to read and copy-paste in your own context for immediate testing).

   Please let me know if you think I'm going the wrong direction with `mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle`.

Comment: Have you considered the naive approach of breaking the action into small pieces and run them in a loop in C#?

Comment: Yes I though about it (also in order to provide a sample application here without all the code behind I added to work with the MCR). I'll probably come back on the issue in the beginning of next year, for now I'm too enrolled into other non related issues (WPF).

Comment: Ok, @CitizenInsane, please update this post if you can, I really need that stuff!

Comment: You're doing this the hardest way possible by reinventing Win32 IPC. Just put the cancel button in Matlab: make a waitbar() and update it inside your for loop. If the user closes the progress bar, your loop will exit.

Comment: I know how to create a full Matlab GUI with waitbars and compile it to exe, but this is not the point here. The idea is to maintain all computation code parts in matlab language (best suited for that kind of stuff); and integrate it as a library along with the rest of the application in .NET (easier and best suited to create GUIs, background threads, etc...). Progression and cancellation are then surveyed from lets say my brand new WPF GUI or whatsoever (i.e. A program in any language calling a compiled matlab routine with basic callback expectations for survey purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it**

`mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle` was effectively the right API function to call at in order to create an array variable (on matlab's side) holding for a function pointer (on external's side). I'm now able to have compiled m-code to call back into my C# code for cancellation and progression purposes.

Correct marshalling for `mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle` is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755730/684399)

Comment: Found this while trying to figure out how to send in a delegate from the C# side to be called by Matlab .. I'm aware this is many years late, but if you still see this, any chance you can post more code? In particular, I'm not sure I understand how your MXArray class looks like .. Thank you.