# PInvoke - How to marshal for 'SomeType* []'?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a native library with some native `ntype` in it and would like to p/invoke some functions in it.

I was able to marshal for:

```
foo1(ntype** p) ==> foo1(IntPtr[] p)
```

But don't know how to do it for:

```
foo1(ntype*[] p) ==> foo1(<???> p)
```

At least `IntPtr[]` did not worked.

**Edit**

The unmanaged function I'm trying to marshal with is:

```
extern mxArray* mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(mxFunctionPtr fcn);
```

where `mxFunctionPtr` is:

```
typedef void(*mxFunctionPtr)(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]);
```

This represent a call to the following matlab function signature:

```
function [varargout] = callback(varargins)
%[
    %% Do callback code %%
%]
```

Obviously, from my expectations, this function pointer should provide me with 2 lists of `mxArray*`:

- The list of input arguments (i.e. prhs, initialized on matlab's side)
- The list of output arguments (i.e. plhs, all initialized to zero but in which I should write into)

Currently from the tests I've made, it only returns for firsts `mxArray*` in `plhs` and `prhs` lists

Comment: C functions that take pointers and arrays are hopelessly ambiguous.  There's no difference between ntype** and ntype*[] unless you somehow gave it different semantics in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it**

The correct marshalling for '`SomeTime* []`' in:

```
extern mxArray* mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(mxFunctionPtr fcn);
typedef void(*mxFunctionPtr)(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray* prhs[]);
```

is:

```
// For function pointer
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public delegate void MCRInteropDelegate(int nlhs,
                                        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysInt, SizeParamIndex = 0)][Out] IntPtr[] plhs, 
                                        int nrhs,
                                        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysInt, SizeParamIndex = 2)][In] IntPtr[] prhs);

// For API function
[DllImport(DLLNAME, EntryPoint = "mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr _mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle(MCRInteropDelegate fctn);
```

**Explanation**

`MarshalAs` attribute indicates to marshal `SomeTime*[]` as a `LPArray` of `IntPtr`, where the size of the array is contained by function's parameter at the zero-based index `SizeParamIndex`

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is to translate your native `ntype` into a managed `struct`.

For instance:

```
public struct Ntype
{
    public int Field1;
    public long Field2;
}
```

Then you define your method with a simple `IntPtr` parameter in your C# code.

```
[DllImport]
static void foo1(IntPtr myParam);
```

Finally here's how you use it:

```
IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

try
{
    // Allocates a buffer. The size must be known
    buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0x1000);

    // Call to your unmanaged method that fills the buffer
    foo1(buffer);

    // Casting the unmanaged memory to managed structure that represents
    // your data
    Ntype obj = (Ntype)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(Ntype));
}
finally
{
    // Free unmanaged memory
    if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't he just not define the structure in both his C# and C++ code, and send the address of the pointer to the C++ code, your suggested code can get people in trouble.

Comment: Thanks @ken2k and @Ramhound for your help. I think I don't really need to have the structure, only a pointer to it is fine for me. In fact i'm trying to solve on calling `mclCreateSimpleFunctionHandle` as described in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7892254/684399). Apparently, this function is only returning for a pointer to the first `mxArray*` and I'm trying to get the full list of `mxArray*` (I'm not interested in `mxArray` itself)... At least for readers on this other post, guess I'm on my way to fix it.