# How to Pass IntPtr to get the data in C#?

Tags: c#

I have one Method called GetUser() in my C++ dll.

```
int GetUser(char *cUserid, USERINFO **pUserInfo); // C++
```

USERINFO is a structure which contains UserInformation
Now when i consume this dll in C# the above API Looks like :

```
int GetUser(string bstrUserId,IntPtr USERINFO); // C#
```

Now the Problem is How to Pass this IntPtr in C# to get the User data of that UserID.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to get a structure from an `IntPtr`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745154/870604).

You might also be able to replace the `IntPtr` type by your structure type (depending on how your structure looks like).

Comment: Some other simple example please.

Comment: Take a look at my question about IntPtr if you can help please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953129/how-to-pass-intptr-between-process-apps